# How to create tabs in a ipad app that is similar a web browser tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have a requirement to create a ipad app that supports tab to view content. I have created a custom splitview controller, whenever user goes to a particular section in the left section, the contents related to that will be displayed in the content view(right view). If a user selects a particular link in that content view it should open a tab and display the contents of that link in that new view. Similar to Web Browser tabs i need to handle tabs in this app. Please suggest any available open source component or any ideas to implement tabbing inside a ipad app.

Comment: Some advice. Apple state a split view controller needs to be the root view controller. This in effect means any tabs need to be implemented within the built in iOS navbar and/or a top-placed toolbar. I would strongly suggest sticking with the split view controller and taking the Navbar/toolbar implementation approach because there is so much support for the new multi-tasking on iPad that is in the split view controller and will continue to be built upon moving forwards. 

Navbars and toolbars at first seem unfriendly, but you can place your own custom views inside them.

Comment: You can implement tabs by placing your own large screen width view in your top placed toolbar and implementing your own tabs as subviews. There amy already be an open source framework that does this. If there isn't I would personally be very concerned to evaluate wether to build my own versus using some other non UISplitViewController subclass solution simply because the split view controller is the future of the iOS UI for this sort of thing in the UI multi-tasking future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Three20 for your tab purpose. Also there are many open Source components available. You just need to search in google.